# Integrate Django and ReactJS with Kafka to generate some analytical data for users?

Tags: reactjs, django, docker, apache-kafka

I'm implementing a Django web service, which is about to have different platform apps,
Reactjs for computers, a swift app for ios, and Kotlin for android devices. the protocol is rest API and perhaps a chat feature included then Django channels are used as well. The data format is JSON. For deployment, I intend to use docker which includes Django, celery, and ReactJS app. And the database is on another separate server which is PostgreSQL. I was thinking to collect some user activity data and some history logs to show the user itself what she/he has done so far. After hours of searching, I came up with Kafka! unfortunately, I have no idea how can I use Kafka and integrate these stuff together and how can I deploy these things. I wish there was a system schema for this specific kind of system that shows what is what and where is what?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Kafka will only integrate your database and Django, with some effort, and ideally a separate Kafka Connect service.

From React (or other clients), you'll need to query some Django API routes which will then query your database. Kafka won't help with your frontend, and isn't really what is exposing the history/activity you're interested in displaying. In other words, you could simply write that to the database, and skip Kafka entirely.

Essentially, you're following the CQRS design pattern if you properly separate Kafka writes from end user / UI reads.

> shows what's what and what's where!

Unclear what this means, but data lineage and metadata tools are a whole separate thing. For example, LinkedIn DataHub collects information such as this

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'm aware that frontend has nothing to do with Kafka, I was just declaring the whole picture of what I'm about to do. I'm thinking of the future after user and data growth for more complicated tasks and data collection which take more process to return a response. I was just curious if it is a big problem that I should be aware of it and do something about it at the beginning of the project.

Comment: If you have asynchronous processes, Kafka can be useful, but plenty of systems today don't use message queues and can still implement similar patterns with just a database